# Network Monitoring devices for bandwidth tracking

Tags: networking, monitoring

I'm looking for preferably a device, but I'll settle for an application. I'd like to get an idea of what is out there. Something just to get a total count from what computer, And maybe by common ports.

I'm not looking for a detailed reporting like wireshark, unless wireshark can do summaries and be running for a whole month without issues.

Essentially, I just want an idea of where my monthly bandwidth is going and by what computers / devices. I.e. computer A does a lot of website traffic, computer B gets a lot of steam downloads, device C has got some virus setting out on an unknown port. Now to be clear, I would only know that Device C has some virus on it as the logs would show either lots of bandwidth on a unknown port which then gets be to investigate.

Being able to ignore / filter any traffic that stays behind the router would be nice. This computer as of this post has over a gig of traffic, but mostly to the networked drive I have, I'm really only interested in what uses internet bandwidth, and who's using it... and if possible, what it is.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  It's closer to a ServerFault.com question, but that site does not allow "shopping" questions http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask for some tools,maybe google/superuser is better for you.

If you ask how to program, you can use `Raw Socket`.

RawSocket is able to work as network sniffer. So you can get your networking bandwidth using.

Comment: that should teach me to not ask questions when i'm tired. thanks.